# Closest antenna to an isotropic?

Tags: antenna

What is the closest antenna ever made to an isotropic antenna? That is, has the same gain in every direction in free space?

Comment: Without some definition of "closeness" to isotropy, this question is not answerable.

Comment: @PhilFrost I think the question *does* define "closeness": closeness to uniform radiation gain in every direction (and it also does specify free space). Slightly more technically, I suppose the same thing could be phrased as that the strength of the far field at a fixed distance from the antenna approaches uniform with regards to elevation and azimuth from the antenna.

Comment: Does it actually need to be designed to radiate a significant fraction of the RF input? Because otherwise, I'd *expect* a dummy load to come pretty close to isotropic; it accepts RF, it radiates some (very small) fraction of it, and it's likely to radiate about equally in all directions.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling it most definitely does not. Which is "closer" to isotropic: an antenna with a pattern in azimuth of $\sin \theta$, or one of $\sin(12\theta)$?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with getting "closer" to isotropic. Some antennas are not directional than others, what antenna has the most gain in all directions ex. An omnidirectional rubber duckie

Comment: @Skyler440 There's no problem with getting closer to isotropy, if you define what "closer" means. How do you map, mathematically, the radiation pattern of some antenna onto some scalar "closeness to isotropy" figure so that we can say which is "more isotropic"?

Comment: As an example of figures you might consider, see [directivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directivity), [beamwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamwidth), or [front-to-back ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-to-back_ratio). All of these quantify "closeness to isotropy" in some way, but they are all different. To answer your question specifically, you need to pick one.

Answer (score 2):

An isotropic antenna *can not exist*. Asking how "close" we can get doesn't really make sense. It's like asking how close we can get to any other impossible thing, like creating [perpetual motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion). Can we say one thing is *closer* to violating the laws of thermodynamics than another? No: all things ever observed obey these laws, no exceptions. Likewise, all antennas ever observed obey [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), so none can be isotropic. Not even a little bit. No exceptions known to science.

How do Maxwell's equations forbid isotropic antennas? I'll explain by analogy. Imagine a ball with some hair on it. Is there any way to comb this hair flat on the ball such that there is not at least one tuft?

[image: hairy ball]

There isn't. This is the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), which states "there is no nonvanishing continuous tangent vector field on even-dimensional n-spheres."

Now, imagine that the hairs are the electric or magnetic field radiating from your antenna. We are looking for a vector field on a sphere, so the "tuft", where the hair sticks straight out, is a vector of zero magnitude. This is a point where there is no radiation.

Why does the hairy ball theorem apply? Because electromagnetic waves are [transverse waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_wave). This is why the tufts count as vectors of zero magnitude and not as vectors sticking out: the *only* direction the lines of force can go in a field that you want to radiate away from that sphere are tangential to the sphere.

Contrast this with sound waves, which are [longitudinal waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave). For these, the lines of force must be perpendicular to the sphere, and an isotropic radiator is easily realized: just make the hair stick straight out everywhere.

So, the consequence of this is that any antenna must not radiate it at least one direction. Beyond that, arbitrary radiation patterns are possible, but none of them are close to isotropic.

Comment: You comment about thermodynamics does not quite work. The thermodynamical laws are formalized as saying that the derivative of entropy is positive. It is still reasonable to ask how close to zero it can be made. Similarly there are metrics that can be used to compare smooth vector fields to nonsmooth vector fields. In particular I am thinking of a Hilbert metric for this. Your comments on the OP are correct though that the method of comparison does need to be specified.

Comment: @BSteinhurst I think it does work, until you define a way to quantify "closeness to free energy". You just defined it as "highest derivative of entropy". Without such a rule comparisons are meaningless though, because nothing is a free energy machine, not even a little bit. The only difference seems to be that there's pretty much one obvious way to quantify perpetual motion, while there are very many ways to quantify isotropy.

Comment: the difference is that the way that the laws of thermodynamics are written (not their hand wavy popularizations) included the quantified notion of entropy and make claims about that. So a serious discussion of thermodynamics has wedded to it a particular way to quantify and measure entropy. This is not the same situation when talking about smooth vector fields since the notion of smooth vector field does not have bound to it a way to measure the difference between two vector fields.

Comment: You begin your answer with _Asking how "close" we can get doesn't really make sense._, and end it with _but none of them are close to isotropic._ (!) So your final conclusion makes no sense, based on your initial assertion?

Comment: By the way, you _can_ have something quite close to an isotropic antenna (in the sense of directivity, let's say), if you relax a key constraint that you did not mention, which is that the waves are all linearly polarized. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0312023v1.pdf .

Comment: @MarkAdler The antenna described in that paper is not _coherent_. It's coherence, not linear polarization, that must be relaxed. Try to build an antenna which radiates coherently a circular (or any other) polarization in every direction and you'll find it's exactly as impossible as a linear isotropic radiator.